# How to get date range control to refresh table data on the same page in Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, date-range

I have a table and a date range control on the report page. My goal: changing date range in the date range control must cause changing the table data according to the date range.

I fail on it: change of dates in the date range control has no influence on the table data. But, if I change dates in the own controls of the table - table changes its content according to dates I set, as expected. This says to me, that the date format in the data source is correct, it is displayed in the field list with a calender icon too.

I tried to achieve the goal on the following way:

- In "current page settings" I selected the data source and as "default date range" I set the same date range, as I set in the table's settings.
- I added data range control to the page, with default date range as in the table settings,
- I set the data range control as report-wide, than s page-wide, selected the option "date range controls on page" - but no setting caused the change of the table data after changing dates.

What yet could I do to achieve my goal?

Here is the screenshop of my setup:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your table is a chart on report page, please make sure you have added your desired date field in the Date Range Dimension option of the table.
To check:

- In the edit mode, select your table
- In setup panel of table, right below the Data Source option, look at the *Date Range Dimension*

Comment: hmm, I don't have it - I update my post, look please on the screenshot

Comment: oh I see the new screenshot, it's maybe because of your data source (Search Console).  I've found in the docs that for GA4 components, it's preset. Sorry I'm not familiar with this so I'm not sure. Please check the doc here to see if you have proper setup: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9272806?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cset-the-date-range-dimension%2Cset-the-default-date-range